# GMAT installation in macOS

Tags: macos, catalina, install, error

I downloaded and tried installing [GMAT](https://gmat.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/GW/overview?mode=global) on macOS Catalina but when I tried to open the application I first got a warning and then I got an error. How to resolve this error?

[image]

[image]

I've run `xattr -dr com.apple.quarantine ~/Downloads/GMAT` but still getting the same error.

```
$ ls -ld GMAT GMAT/R2018a GMAT/R2018a/bin GMAT/R2018a/bin/gmat_startup_file.txt
drwxr-xr-x 4 ayushmehta staff 128 Sep 23 13:20 GMAT
drwx------ 15 ayushmehta staff 480 Sep 23 13:21 GMAT/R2018a
drwxr-xr-x 11 ayushmehta staff 352 Sep 23 13:24 GMAT/R2018a/bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 ayushmehta staff 10432 Apr 20 2018 GMAT/R2018a/bin/gmat_startup_file.txt
```